# I have a problem my basic project in javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

```js
        var rect_arr_c = new Array();
       
        var ct = 0;
        var rect = {
            start:function(){
                this.interval = setInterval(rect.update,120);
                
                this.cnv = document.createElement("canvas");
                this.ctx = this.cnv.getContext("2d");
                this.cnv.width = 500;
                this.cnv.height = 500;
                this.cnv.style.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";
                document.body.insertBefore(this.cnv,document.body.childNodes[0]);

            },
            update:function()
            {
                rect.ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
                c_rect_arr();
                for(var i = 0;i<ct;i++)
                {
                    
                    rect.ctx.fillRect(rect_arr_c[i].x,rect_arr_c[i].y,rect_arr_c[i].width,rect_arr_c[i].width);
                    move_rect();
                    
                }
            }  
        }

        function c_rect()
        {
            if(ct > 1)
            {
                this.width = Math.floor(Math.random()*21);
                this.vx = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1); // speed in x axis of rectangle from 1 to 10
                this.vy = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);// speed in y axis of rectangle from 1 to 10
                this.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(501-(this.width + this.vx)));
                this.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(501-(this.width +this.vy)));
                
            }
            else
            {
                this.width = Math.floor(Math.random()*21);
                this.vx = Math.floor((Math.random() *10)+1);
                this.vy = Math.floor((Math.random() *10) +1);
                this.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(501));
                this.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(501));
                
            }
            
        }
        function move_rect()
        {
            
            for(var i = 0;i<ct;i++)
            {
                
                if(rect_arr_c[i].x > 500 || rect_arr_c[i].x < 0)
                {
                    rect_arr_c[i].vx *= -1;
                }
                if(rect_arr_c[i].y > 500 || rect_arr_c[i].y < 0)
                {
                    rect_arr_c[i].vy *= -1;
                }

                rect_arr_c[i].x +=  rect_arr_c[i].vx;
                rect_arr_c[i].y +=  rect_arr_c[i].vy;
                    
            }
        }
        function c_rect_arr()
        {
            
            rect_arr_c[ct] = new c_rect();
            ct+=1;

        }
rect.start();
```

I'm trying a simple project that creating rectangles with calling c_rect_arr(). My problem is when I'm trying create a new rect with c_rect_arr() function, speeds of the creating rects are increasing although I didn't expect this.I couldn't find why is this happening.If you help me,I will be happy.Thank you from now.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I can't see lagging on my computer (M1 Chip) with your example, now depending on what you actually like to achieve here, creating a lot of rectangles and keeping them in memory plus moving them at some point will slow down the update rate.

Comment: You're adding a new rectangle during every single frame. That's going to cause a slow-down. Next, I look at your `c_rect` function. You've got some mistakes in your formulas here. `this.vx = Math.floor((Math.random() + 1)*10);` - the comment next to this is wrong. The code will give you a range in the region of 10 to 20, not 1 to 10. `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1. Then you add 1 to this, so it ranges from 1 to 2. Next, you multiply it by 10, taking it from 10 to 20, finally rounding it down. 10 will occur _much_ more often than 20. ;) The next line's comment is also poor.

Comment: @enhzflep I fixed that but this is not my main problem

Comment: @OsmanB - No you didn't. `this.vy = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);// speed in x axis of rectangle from 1 to 10` You removed 3 characters from the question body. This is still a copy/paste error (VY set, comment talks about X axis). Perhaps you will consider telling us what you're expecting and how that's different from what you're getting? You may wish to take the tour for new users, which explains a bit about the place and expectations placed upon its users, as found here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour